# Display horizontal scrollbar and force horizontal overflow in LI elements

Tags: html, css, overflow, positioning, scrollbars

I have some CSS and HTML that are as follows. There's a javascript code that turns the .tab into a tabbed element of #tab-container. Since #tab-container has fixed width and height if content of .tab exceeds width/height either is becomes hidden or overflows. In the case of UL, I want it to overflow and have scrollbars within the div.tab . Only a horizontal scrollbar should appear. I tried with the code below, but for some reason I can only manage to scroll vertically (LI  fill the width limit, then more rows appear... I want only one row + horizontal scroll). I think I can't really change the two DIVs otherwise the tabs will be broken. I need a solution within the .tab layer.

the HTML:

```
<div id="tab-container">
    <div class="tab">
       <ul>
           <li><img src="img01.png" width="96" height="96" /></li>
           <li><img src="img02.png" width="96" height="96" /></li>
           <li><img src="img03.png" width="96" height="96" /></li>
           <li><img src="img04.png" width="96" height="96" /></li>
       </ul>
</div>
```

the CSS:

```
#tab-container { width: 500px; height: 200px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; } 
.tab { position: relative; overflow: hidden;}
#tab-container .tab ul { position: absolute; width: auto; display: block; overflow: scroll; }
#tab-container .tab ul li { display: inline-block; position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

to

```
.tab {
  overflow-x: scroll; /* or auto, if you don't want the scroll bar visible all of the time. */
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

If you find your stuff is still wrapping, you may need to add `white-space: nowrap` to your div.tabs, or the <li>s.

Additionally, your ul's `position: absolute` is likely going to interfere with what you want. `position: absolute` takes the element out of the document flow, so it may not behave the way you want it to. If you find that it is misbehaving, try changing it to `position: relative`.